# How can I render Excel files on browser for free?(site working with js and python on Django in Azure )

Tags: javascript, python, html, jquery, azure

For instance, you click the file and it will download. But I want to it opens in new tab like that SharePoint. But I can't use SharePoint for security stuff. It want the read all of company files

[image: if you click this xls file it must open new tab]

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear what the actual problem you are facing as you have not provided any code. But from what I understand, as you are using **JavaScript** in your application then you can solve your problem by using **JavaScript Window open method**.

The **window.open()** is a pre-defined window method of JavaScript used to open the new tab or window in the browser. This will depend on your browser setting or parameters passed in the window.open() method that either a new window or tab will open.

#### Syntax

This function accepts four parameters, but they are optional as shown below.

```
window.open(URL, name, specs, replace);
```

#### Example

You can use the below code snippet as example and solve the problem you are facing.

```html
#just an example
<html>
<body>
<script>
  function openWindow() {
    window.open('your url');
  }
</script>
    
Click the button to open new tab <br>
<button  onclick="openWindow()"> Open Window </button>
</body>
</html>
```

Check this [JavaScript Window open method tutorial](https://www.javatpoint.com/javascript-window-open-method) for more information.